# How i can fetch data as unicode in Execute SQL TASK in SSIS

Tags: oracle, ssis, execute-sql-task

I have developing a project in SSIS.
First I drag and drop a `Execute SQL TASK` in ControlFlow.
After that I write a query in `Execute SQL TASK` like this :

```
 select 'رضا','خدائی' from dual
```

And in `Result Set` I add two new variables, `Fname` and `LName` with index `0`,`1`.
But when I debug the package, the values of these two variables are `'???'`, `'????'`

My oracle character set is 'AL32UTF8'. I tested the code page of `Execute SQL TASK` in 1252, 1256, 65001, but in all code pages, I cannot solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should always use N before your string likes `N'رضا'`
Not only in this case, it would be better to use it in all your queries which you have unicode strings.
You can also change your ExecuteSQLTask codepage to 65001 or use CAST() too.